# Как на canvas добавить form с элементами?

Tags: javascript, websocket

Делаю игру наподобие BrowserQuest. Застрял на форме регистрации игрока. Собственно сабж, как ее реализовать для canvas?

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <canvas id="canvas1" width="1200" height="800"></canvas>    
        </body>
        <script>
         var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
         var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
....
        </script>
    </html>
```

Как в ctx можно добавить форму..логин..пароль и т.д.?
Пытаюсь таким образом:

```
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('action',"submit.php");

//create input element
var i = document.createElement("input");
i.type = "text";
i.name = "user_name";
i.id = "user_name1";

//create a checkbox
var c = document.createElement("input");
c.type = "checkbox";
c.id = "checkbox1";
c.name = "check1";

//create a button
var s = document.createElement("input");
s.type = "submit";
s.value = "Submit";

// add all elements to the form
f.appendChild(i);
f.appendChild(c);
f.appendChild(s);

canvas.appendChild(f); //pure javascript
```

Отдельно страничка регистрации не пойдет, так как игрок попадает в игру.

Сначала с именем как "unknown". Затем должна появляться форма регистрации/авторизации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; margin: 0px 0 0 -90px; top: 30%; width:180px; height:110px;   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#dff0d8), to(#c8e5bc)); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#dff0d8 0%, #c8e5bc 100%); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#dff0d8 0%, #c8e5bc 100%);background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#dff0d8 0%, #c8e5bc 100%);background-image: linear-gradient(#dff0d8 0%, #c8e5bc 100%);border-color: #b2dba1;-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;">
            <div style="text-align: center; ">
              <p>Вход в систему</p>
..... buttons...
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`canvas` рисует лишь графику, поэтому если вы хотите форму авторизации в игре, вы либо ее рисуете, либо как вариант полегче (намного): поверх `canvas` отобразить блок с формой авторизации, как обычный `html`

Comment: спасибо, смысл понял и уже нарисовал. а как с такой формой передать в ws данные? вешать обработчик на кнопку? а как картинку передать?

Comment: @Anonymous, что для вас `ws`? Картинку передать куда?

Comment: ws=websocket. я пытаюсь сделать игру наподобии browserquest.mozilla.org. у них очень простая авторизация только имя. а я хочу еще фотку аватарки устанавливать.